# Paperclip Amazon S3 setup with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

`has_attached_file :image, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml", :path => "/:style/:filename"`

I'm not sure what  `:path => "/:style/:filename"` is.

I also want to to include the style for this attached image, is that what the :path is?
the style I want is this: `:styles => { :medium => "275x275>", :thumb => "175x155>" }`

Basically what's going on here is that I'm setting up on `heroku` and I'm having to use S3 which seems straightforward just not used to this attachment convention stuff.

Also, I just signed up for an S3 account... but `heroku` was spouting that its free or something. What's the deal with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'path' specifies the location on S3 where the files will be stored. Thus, if you specify an attachment as:

```
 has_attached_file :image, 
    :styles => { :medium => "275x275>", :thumb => "175x155>" },
    :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
    :path => "user/:attachment/:style/:id.:extension"
```

A sample URL will be:

> http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/user/image/thumb/347853856.jpg

Finally, S3 is NOT free (Heroku simply states transfer / uploads are not counted in the usage based calculations). Heroku's [documentation](http://docs.heroku.com/s3) is excellent if you need further information.

Comment: Kevin:  Does Paperclip still require you to write to the local file system on Heroku for any files that you upload?  For instance, does the file goto the Heroku dyno first (especially for processed images), then to S3?  Or can Paperclip go directly to S3 and bypass Heroku?

Comment: @iWasRobbed Paperclip will be running in your Rails application and thus be running on Heroku. In this case, the file will go through Heroku first.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in Rails 3.1 and above, it should be Rails.root and not RAILS_ROOT