# Not able to post new content after putting AWS S3 on my Heroku Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and to practice I decided to build out Dribble type App (Mackenszie Child youtube series). I was able to build it and deploy it successfully to Heroku and in my local environment. However, I also wanted to practice putting my images on Amazon Web Services S3 - that's when the problem started. I can deploy to heroku but when I want to start a new post I'm prompted with an error "We're sorry, but something went wrong." I have listed below my heroku app link, my github repository, my heroku logs, my production rb file, and my postrb (model) - [i feel that is where I might be tripping up]. Thank you guys so much for helping me out.

Similar Stackoverflow Methods that I tried without success but got me close i feel:

1 - Very Close) [Rails 4: Heroku + Paperclip + s3 not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098534/rails-4-heroku-paperclip-s3-not-working-in-production)

2) [Paperclip Amazon S3 setup with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435246/paperclip-amazon-s3-setup-with-heroku?rq=1)

---

Github Repository: https://github.com/OmarZV/muse

My Heroku App Site: https://intense-shelf-74152.herokuapp.com/

Heroku Latest Logs:

```
2016-07-27T14:58:19.093639+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v16 created by oek203@nyu.edu
2016-07-27T14:58:19.093594+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach PAPERTRAIL (@ref:papertrail-spherical-45365) by oek203@nyu.edu
2016-07-27T14:58:26.753023+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-27 14:58:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-07-27T14:58:26.753289+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-27 14:58:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=12517
2016-07-27T14:58:26.753041+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-27 14:58:26] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-07-27T14:58:27.146586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-07-27T14:59:12.660585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=intense-shelf-74152.herokuapp.com request_id=b5bc6545-aa59-4c48-93d1-0e6d2e1b7f8f fwd="66.150.113.6" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=124ms status=200 bytes=2037
2016-07-27T14:59:14.551411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts/new" host=intense-shelf-74152.herokuapp.com request_id=cd6d6784-b3ee-42a7-abad-f08380cd8be2 fwd="66.150.113.6" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=38ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-07-27T15:03:08.539026+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=intense-shelf-74152.herokuapp.com request_id=384f66f6-9bb0-4805-a396-5dcddd41685b fwd="66.150.113.6" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=2037
2016-07-27T15:03:10.358959+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts/new" host=intense-shelf-74152.herokuapp.com request_id=84d96bfe-fa4f-40a0-9eb8-28b40dc83aba fwd="66.150.113.6" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Production RB:

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :debug
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
#Setting up paperclip for AWS
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
end
```

Post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "700x500#", small: "350x250>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Comment: what is the error ..can you check using papertrail...?post it

Comment: hope you have properly configured AWS using aws-sdk gem and credentials needed to authenticate using something like s3.yml which must hold your development/production access_key_id,bucket and secret-access-key...?

Comment: Milind, thank you for your response. I've updated the question to show my production rb - wherein you'll notice that I've followed the heroku guide exactly - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3. 
> The guide never mentioned anything about s3.yml

Comment: Milind, I also just added my heroku logs and the error is that a user is not able to post new content because they are not able to reach > https://intense-shelf-74152.herokuapp.com/posts/new
A message appears saying "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the app owner check the logs for more info"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after constantly working on it - the issue had to do with the endpoints, bucket name and my host name. This screwed things around in the following way.

In order to add an image, I had to do:
1. heroku config:unset AWS_BUCKET 
2. heroku config:set AWS_BUCKET = kamari1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
3. heroku config:unset 
4. heroku config:set AWS_BUCKET = kamari1

I solved this by looking at the aws s3 console and configuring my endpoints so that they were being directed appropriately. After that make sure to run the following command "heroku pg:reset DATABASE" and you will be a happy camper :)

AWS_BUCKET:               kamari1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

S3_HOST_NAME:             s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvmxL.png